# How to solve linear differential equations such as $y''-7y'+10y=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks to solve the linear equation

$$y''-7y'+10y=0$$

I'm not sure where to even start.

I'm new to this so it would be nice if I got an in depth explanation ( with rules too )

Thank you!

Comment: ok, when are we moving onto the system of differential equations?

Comment: Can you **please** start writing titles that describe your specific problem? I'm getting tired of editing your stream of identical non-descriptive titles.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure others will rush in and give you the solution to your particular equation.

Answering this question the way you want requires a whole lecture in ODEs. I recommend watching this good one from MIT on the exact topic, *Solving second order linear ODEs with constant coefficients*:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-9-solving-second-order-linear-odes-with-constant-coefficients/

or equivalently

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP-oRQqmeg4#t=30

Comment: Thank you so much for the videos!

Answer (score 1):

To take a step back from going straight to the characteristic equation.

If you guess a solution of the form $y=e^{kt}$ for some constant $k$, then the differential equation becomes
$$k^2e^{kt}-7ke^{kt}+10e^{kt}=0$$

Thus $(k^2-7k+10)e^{kt}=0$.

Thus $k^2-7k+10=0$.  So $k=5$ or $k=2$.

This gives two basic solutions of $y_1=e^{5t}$ and $y_2=e^{2t}$.  The general solution is then found by taking arbitrary linear combinations of these two basic solutions.

As Simon S points out in his answer, there is really a lot going on here, and it is hard to do a problem like this justice in a short posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief overview of a solution from first principles which justifies the short-cut methods normally used.

Suppose you have the equation $$y'=ky$$ Consider the function $$z=ye^{-kt}$$ so that $$z'=y'e^{-kt}-kye^{-kt}=(y'-ky)e^{-kt}=0$$

From the mean value theorem we then know that $z=C$, a constant, and this gives a general solution $y=Ce^{kt}$.

---

Now, with $y''-7y'+10y=0$ note that the roots of the quadratic $x^2-7x+10=0$ are $2$ and $5$. This motivates the next stage, which is to rewrite first as $$(y''-5y')-(2y'-10y)=0$$

Let $v=y'-5y$, then $v'=2v$ and we have the solution $v=Ae^{2t}$

Similarly we write $$(y''-2y')-(5y'-10y)=0$$ and set $w=y'-2y$. We then have $w'=5w$ and $w=Be^{5t}$

---

Now we write $v,w$ in terms of $y', y$ so that we have the two equations $$y'-5y=Ae^{2t}$$ and $$y'-2y=Be^{5t}$$

Subtract the first from the second to eliminate $y'$ and note that $A,B$ were arbitrary constants, so divide by $3$. We obtain the general solution $$y=Ce^{5t}+De^{2t}$$

Answer (score -2):

Your differential equation has characteristic equation $t^2-7t+10=0$, which forces $t=-5,-2$. Therefore the solutions are of the form $f(x)=Ae^{5t}+Be^{2t}$.

Comment: Please check your characteristic roots.

Comment: oops. Thanks, paw.